# Request instance within ConfigureServices

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Within `ConfigureServices` I'm setting up a number of services (this works). In the same method I'm trying to configure a custom file provider (for Razor). It looks like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.FileProvider = new CustomFileProvider(???);
        });
```

`CustomFileProvider` has a few dependencies (that are all configured), but how can I ask the DI to give me an instance of `CustomFileProvider` right after all the services have been configured?

From what I can see the DI only injects in constructors, but in my case I need a "please give me an instance of `CustomFileProvider` right here" option.

Comment: You can't resolve within ConfigureServices as the container is built after `ConfigureServices` is called and before `Configure` is called. If you don't have a very complex dependency structure for the file provider, you should inject them manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to resolve services from the container while configuring some options, you need to leverage the `IConfigureOptions<TOption>` infrastructure, which most of MVC uses to set up the option defaults. See [RazorViewEngineOptionsSetup](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c15cf49a73673d350bf9c5cd9b41a51fdabf346c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorViewEngineOptionsSetup.cs#L31-L34) for an example.

First, add the services you need to the collection:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IDependency1, Dependency1>();
services.AddSingleton<IDependency2, Dependency2>();
```

Then, implement the setup class:

```cs
public class CustomFileProviderRazorViewEngineOptionsSetup : ConfigureOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>
{
    public CustomFileProviderRazorViewEngineOptionsSetup(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(options => ConfigureRazor(options, serviceProvider))
    {
    }

    private static void ConfigureRazor(RazorViewEngineOptions options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Alternative 1 - Resolve each service and new up the instance.
        var dependency1 = serviceProvider.GetService<IDependency1>();
        var dependency2 = serviceProvider.GetService<IDependency2>();

        options.FileProviders.Add(new CustomFileProvider(dependency1, dependency2));

        // Alternative 2 - Same as alternative 1, but with moar magic ;)
        options.FileProviders.Add(ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<CustomFileProvider>(serviceProvider));

        // Alternative 3 - Just resolve CustomFileProvider from the service provider.
        // This requires it to be registered first, of course.
        options.FileProviders.Add(serviceProvider.GetService<CustomFileProvider>());
    }
}
```

This is resolved from the container, so it'll allow you to inject an `IServiceProvider`, which can again be used to resolve the services you need. You could optionally add the `CustomFileProvider` to the container and resolve that directly instead, like in alternative 3.

Finally, add the setup class to the service collection:

```cs
services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Transient<
        IConfigureOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>,
        CustomFileProviderRazorViewEngineOptionsSetup>());
```

This will add the setup to the options builder pipeline, which means it'll run with the other registered instances of `IConfigureOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>` to setup the options object.

Comment: +1. You could even use `options.FileProviders.Add(ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, typeof(CustomFileProvider)))` to simplify the instantiation a bit.

Comment: Yep. Added a couple of alternatives :)