# Using IConfigureOptions to configure an injected dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 WebApi project and am trying to initialize an injected dependency with some custom options before using it in my controllers. After searching online I found a few articles ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648159/request-instance-within-configureservices/37659050#37659050), [here](http://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions/) and [here](http://benjamincollins.com/blog/using-dependency-injection-while-configuring-services/) explaining how to use IConfigureServices to do just this. Seems pretty simple! Unfortunately, I can't get it to work and I can't figure out why, I'm sure it must be a simple oversight..

I have created a simple project, and added the following classes to illustrate the most basic scenario:

```
public class Tester
{
    public void Initialize(TestOptions options)
    {
        //do something with options.
    }
}

public class TestConfigurator : IConfigureOptions<TestOptions>
{
    private Tester _tester;

    public TestConfigurator(Tester tester)
    {
        _tester = tester;
    }

    public void Configure(TestOptions options)
    {
        _tester.Initialize(options);
    }
}

public class TestOptions
{
}
```

The 'Tester' class gets injected into the constructor of a Controller class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public ValuesController(Tester tester)
    {
        //do something with tester..
    }
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Finally, I have added the following configuration in ConfigureServices of the Startup class:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<Tester, Tester>();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<TestOptions>, TestConfigurator>();
    }
```

When I run the project and call the 'api/values' call, the Tester class is created and injected into the ValuesController, but the TestConfigurator class never gets constructed and so the class never gets Initialized with the options class. What am I missing?

UPDATE
The answers below are of course all valid to this simplified example. I realize now that I oversimplified a bit, as the dependency I'm using (illustrated here as Tester) is from a 3rd party library, so I don't have the constructor to play with. Wrapping the 3rd party class in an extended class will do the trick, but if anybody has an alternative suggestion on manipulating it without modifying its constructor, then I'm still open to suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something or you need to add `services.AddSingleton<TestConfigurator, TestConfigurator>();` to your `ConfigureServices()` method to register `TestConfigurator` type?

Comment: are you getting an exception or does it just equal to null?

Comment: There is no exception and the object is not null, the execution just doesn't enter the configuration classes.

Comment: @Ignas The last line of code should take care of that, binding it by interface, but I tried your suggestion too and it makes no difference unfortunately.

Comment: @Ignas The Options framework should take of that. If you take a look at [link](http://benjamincollins.com/blog/using-dependency-injection-while-configuring-services/), it says _"What you have to do is implement IConfigureOptions<TOptions> for whatever TOptions you need to configure, and then add that to the container. When the Options framework invokes all of its configurations, it will resolve classes of type IConfigureOptions<> and then invoke the Configure method on them."_

Comment: @Chris look at my updated answer

Comment: For anyone running into this behavior where your Configure() method is not called on ASP.NET Core 2+: You need to implement the IConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions> interface instead of IConfigureOptions<TOptions> or your Configure() method will not be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, now I got it, I feel silly for all the edits.

you are using `IOptions` wrong, and it got me all confused.

implementing a custom `IConfigurationOptions<>` gives you the abilty to either configure your options from database, or to just use a different class (instead of a lambda)

what you are trying to do, is instantiate a Tester class based on those options, this is fine - but it's not the `IConfigureOptions<>` job.

in order to initialize your `Tester` class based on the `TestOptions` you should create a constructor on the `Tester` class that receives it like this

```
public class Tester
{
    public Tester(IOptions<TestOptions> options)
    {
        //do something with options.
    }
}
```

and what you are trying to do will work.

Comment: My bad, I fixed it - now I am certain this is what you missed

Comment: either that or `IOptions<TestOptions>` but give me a second to make sure

Comment: Ah, indeed.. looks like I misinterpreted the IConfigureOptions model then. Your solution works and is much simpler, thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I remember why I went down this path. You see, in my simplified example, the Tester class is part of the same project, but in my real project, this dependency is from a 3rd party library, so the Options in the constructor isn't possible without wrapping the 3rd party class. If there is no other way of doing it, then I guess that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: in that case, I would create a "factory" class, that will contain a `Tester` property, which will be initialized using the `TestOptions`

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [Asp.Net Core Configuration Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) and adapted to your example

Assuming

```
public class TestOptions {
    public string SomeOption { get; set; }
}
```

> Options can be injected into your application using the
>   `IOptions<TOptions>` accessor service.

You could try abstracting `Tester` and registering that with the service collection.

```
public interface ITester {
    //tester contract    
}

public class Tester : ITester {
    public Tester(IOptions<TestOptions> options) {
        //do something with test options.
    }
}
```

> To setup the `IOptions<TOptions>` service you call the `AddOptions`
>   extension method during startup in your `ConfigureServices` method.
>   You configure options using the `Configure<TOptions>` extension method.
>   You can configure options using a delegate or by binding your options
>   to configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    // Setup options with DI
    services.AddOptions();

    // Configure TestOptions using config by installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
    services.Configure<TestOptions>(Configuration);

    // Configure TestOptions using code
    services.Configure<TestOptions>(testOptions => {
        testOptions.SomeOption = "value1_from_action";
    });

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add your services.
    services.AddSingleton<ITester, Tester>();
}
```

And finally just refactor the controller to depend on the abstraction instead of the concretion.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller {
    public ValuesController(ITester tester) {
        //do something with tester..
    }
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is TestOptions supposed to come from?  Are you trying to get it mapped auto-magically from your settings file?  I think you are over-thinking how this should work, unless there is some reason you have to use `initialize` instead of constructor injection.

All you are trying to do is make some options available to tester, right?

If so, just use the basic `IOptions` features - no need to go advanced with `IConfigureOptions`

```
public class Tester
{
    private TestOptions _options;
    public Tester(IOptions<TestOptions> options)
    {
       _options = options.Value;
    }
}
// don't need this anymore
/* public class TestConfigurator : IConfigureOptions<TestOptions>
{
    private Tester _tester;

    public TestConfigurator(Tester tester)
    {
        _tester = tester;
    }

    public void Configure(TestOptions options)
    {
        _tester.Initialize(options);
    }
}
*/
public class TestOptions
{
}
```

And then configure the options using one of the two methods below (depending on whether it comes from config or has to be manually constructed).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<Tester, Tester>();
        // Configure TestOptions using config 
        services.Configure<TestOptions>(Configuration);

        // Configure MyOptions using code
        services.Configure<TestOptions>(testOptions =>
        {
           // initialize them here, e.g. testOptions.Foo = "Bar"
        });
}
```